# How to implement webdriver wait on list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

How can i implement webdriver wait for a list of elements return by the driver? I can get it work by implementing time.sleep, but is there a proper way to implement webdriver wait function? I have tried something like 
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(i))

But it seems like the EC.element_to_be_clickable does not accept i.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.btn-grid.btn.btn-default')

if len(elems) < 1:
    raise Exception('No items found.') 
else:

    for i in elems:
        time.sleep(3)  
        #WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(i))   
        i.click()
```